# how to public static content with jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I'm currently running an app in Tomcat and I want it to run it in Jetty.

My Tomcat configuration is as follows:

- 1 war
- 1 module that exposes images

some code of my Tomcat's server.xml:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Executor maxThreads="300" minSpareThreads="50" name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="tomcat-http--"/>
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
        </Realm>
        <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="true" deployXML="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
            <Context docBase="/home/neuquino/svn_co/FrameworkIMG/img" path="/img" reloadable="true"/>
            <Context docBase="myapp-web" path="/" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:myapp-web"/>
        </Host>
    </Engine>
    <Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="${bio.http.port}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
</Service>
```

The thing I'm not able to reproduce in Jetty is the one configured in this line:

```
<Context docBase="/home/neuquino/svn_co/FrameworkIMG/img" path="/img" reloadable="true"/>
```

**Here is my jetty-maven-plugin configuration**:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <war>${basedir}/target/myapp.war</war>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The *difference* is that in /home/neuquino/svn_co/FrameworkIMG/img I don't have a webApp, the directory simply contains folders and files (in this case images)

So, the question is: How I can expose static content with Jetty?

It is not necessary to tell me how to do it with maven's plugin, If you know how to do it with a standalone jetty distribution it also helps me a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm using v9.0.4.v20130625 of jetty-maven-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, here it is:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <war>${basedir}/target/myapp.war</war>
                </webApp>
                <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                    <contextPath>/img</contextPath>
                    <resourceBase>/home/neuquino/svn_co/FrameworkIMG/img</resourceBase>
                    <handler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler" />
                </contextHandler>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Neuquino answered to himself, the solution it is, but with one exception: latest version of jetty requires to wrap context handlers to special section, like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <contextHandlers>
                    <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
                        <contextPath>/avatar/tmp</contextPath>
                        <resourceBase>/usr/local/resources/webapp/avatar/tmp</resourceBase>
                        <handler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler" />
                    </contextHandler>
                </contextHandlers>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <stopWait>10</stopWait>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It works for me.